# java server/client save a downloadad file NOT to HDD

Tags: java

Im receiving a file trough this code and the "bos.write" are saving it o to my HDD.
Everything working good.
Since im sending the file in a few second i thought i could store the file in memory
instead of HDD.
Now how do i do this?

```
File path = new File("C://anabella//test1.txt");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
    int size = 1024;
    int val = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (fileSize >0) {
       val = in.read(buffer, 0, size);
       bos.write(buffer, 0, val);
       fileSize -= val;
       if (fileSize < size)
       size = (int) fileSize;
    }
```

Comment: Are you explicitly writing the data to a file? Maybe you should add some more of your code and indent it by 4 spaces to make it look cleaner.

Comment: just be careful that you have a tight constraint on the max size of the file.  otherwise, you could use this code to download a 2GB file and blow out the memory on your jvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the size in advance you don't even need a ByteArrayOutputStream

```
 InputStream is = socket.getInputStream(); // or where ever the inputstream comes from.
 DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(is);
 byte[] bytes = new byte[fileSize];
 in.readFully(bytes);
```

to send the bytes to any OutputStream like

```
 OutputStream os = ...
 os.write(bytes);
```

The bytes will contain the contents of the file.

Comment: And to send the "byte" to a receiving DataInputStream over the Internet i guess my original code abowe can be used

Comment: Yes i have the size in advance but how do i attache the "bytes" to a DataOutputStream bos = new DataOutputStream(byte???);
I know this was a new Question, sorry

Comment: ofcource
ByteArrayInputStream byt = new ByteArrayInputStream (buffer);
DataInputStream bos = new DataInputStream(byt);

Comment: On the receiving side I have     byte[] buffer = new byte[fileSize];     in.readFully(buffer);     But it gives me EOFException,     Any Ide?

Comment: readLong and readUTF works just before readFully. Maybe Buffer size is the problem

Comment: That means there isn't as much data as you think, or what is more likely is that the format isn't exactly right, are you sure that the readUTF() is correct and doesn't have any corrupt character at the end. I suspect it is reading too much data which would look fine until you tried to read the read of the data.

Comment: The two first works but not readFully it really crash hard in LogCat.    long fileSize = in.readLong();    String fileName = in.readUTF();    in.readFully(buffer);

Comment: Im running this from a Java server in Eclipse sending to android AVD phone emulator. Perhaps thats the problem

Comment: Do you mean "works" as in has valid data, i.e. you check the data is valid by printing it out? or do you mean "works" as in it doesn't report an error but could contain corrupt data. If a read() fails it is very often because the previous read left the stream in an incorrect state.

Comment: Problems solved.
Installing the app on my HTC desire phone did the trick.
Dont ask me why

Answer (score 4):

Presumably `bos` is a FileOutputStream? To use an in-memory buffer use a ByteArrayOutputStream instead.